# The right use of 'manifest'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I'm not sure whether I'm using the word **manifest** correctly. For example, today at work my work mate said he only sees me when it's getting busy and I said jokingly:

> *I just manifest when you need me.*

Is this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, 'manifest' (verb, no object) meaning 'appear' is used about ghosts or spirits, but would be understood if used in a jocular sense about a person, especially if humorously likening them to a spirit, demon, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're a ghost or a spirit. According to [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/manifest):

> *(no object) (of a ghost or spirit)* **appear**.
>   **Example**:
>   *one deity manifested in the form of a bird*

Otherwise, **manifest** should only be used as a verb when you want to, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manifest):

> (to) make evident or certain by showing or displaying

**manifest**, in this sense, is often used to refer to abstract concepts or emotions rather than actual, tangible objects. Example:

> *Her behavior problems began manifesting themselves soon after she left home.*

Answer (score 0):

**manifest**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/manifest)

> clearly revealed to the mind or the senses or judgment; Choose the
>   verb manifest when someone shows something for everyone to notice.

As in your sentence with a slight modification, the usage is correct in AmE:

> I just manifest myself when you need me.

There are other senses of 'to manifest', ghostly is but one. [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/113484?rskey=zlAntL&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)